# Make Python3.6 the default interpreter when running the command python filename.py in terminal?

Tags: python, python3

I have three versions of python on ubuntu 18.04
when running `python -V` in terminal it produces `Python 2.7.15rc1`
and when running `python3 -V` it produces `Python 3.7.2`

You could see the paths of python versions on my OS from this picture [here is the screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPK2.png)

**but when running `pip install package-name` or `pip3 install package-name` it installs the `package` in `python3.6`,**

**Now as all the packages installed on python3.6**, I want to run my programs in terminal on python3.6 not `Python 2.7.15rc1` or `Python 3.7.2`
[as in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXlsc.png)

**My problem is:**
when I run `python filename.py`, it interpreted on `Python 2.7.15rc1` so it produces an error that says package not found, and the same when running `python3 filename.py` it interpreted on `Python 3.7.2` and it produces an error that says package not found

Now I want to set `Python3.6` to be the default interpreter when I run a program in the terminal because it has all the packages installed to it!

Comment: Are you setting the header on the file.py? #!/usr/bin/env python [Header thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/what-is-the-common-header-format-of-python-files)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add alternatives for pythhon...

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 3
   ```

   Notice that the numbers: 1, 2, 3. Add other alternatives if needed, remembering to increment the number. Also note that the paths such a `/usr/bin/python3.6` in the above commands must point to the installed python on your system.
2. Select a default python using the command line:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config python
   ```

   You will be presented with a list, and required to pick a number 1, 2, or 3.
3. Optionally, if you want to use a GUI to switch default pythons...

   ```
   sudo apt install galternatives
   ```

   Then launch the Alternatives Configurator app, scroll down to "python" and select which python you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

On your system `/usr/bin/python3` is likely a link to `/usr/bin/python3.7` and can be changed to be `/usr/bin/python3.6`. You will also find that `/usr/bin/python` is a link to `/usr/bin/python2.7`×

The link for `python3` can be changed to be `/usr/bin/python3.6` but making `python` itself default to `python3` is fraught with peril, because your system may have scripts written for python v2(*) with a `#! /usr/bin/python` shebang and changing `python` to be a python V3 interpreter will break them.

Another solution is to define a shell alias (in .bashrc)

```
alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.6
alias python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

The good thing about this solution is that it only changes the meaning of `python` for interactive shells, in scripts the aliases are ignored and you still use the default `python` interpreter and so won't break anything.

(*) Find them with:

```
find /usr/ -type f -executable -exec grep -E -l '#!.+python[^3]' {} \;
```