# Make add-apt-repository use python3.7 instead of python3

Tags: 16.04, python, add-apt-repository

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm trying to use `sudo add-apt-repository` , but I'm getting the `module apt_pkg not found` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Doing a simple `ls /usr/bin | grep "python"` shows that I have 3 folders : `python3`, `python3.5` and `python3.7`. My default Python version has been set to 3.7 (uses `python3 <command>`).

The `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` file has python3 mentioned in the header:

`#! /usr/bin/python3`

I tried these answers I found online:

1- Changing `#! /usr/bin/python3` to `#! /usr/bin/python3.7`

2- Doing `sudo apt-get remove python3-apt` followed by `sudo apt-get install python3-apt`

But still no luck. How do make it use python3.7 instead of python3, or anything else that'll solve this error?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1307228/100356

Comment: Tried that. At the end when I run `sudo update-alternatives --config python`, the first line is `* 0            /usr/bin/python3.7   3         auto mode`

Even after setting the alternative as option 3 (which is also python3.7), it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Followed [this blog](https://www.programmersought.com/article/1003529676/).

It has a solution for Ubuntu 14.04 but it also works for Ubuntu 16. Since the python version he's trying to achieve is different than mine, I made some tweaks. This the final procedure:

1-`sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-apt`

2-`sudo apt-get install python3-apt -f`

3-`cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`

4-`sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-3?m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`